# compojure/clojure GET route with CSS gives plain text stylesheet response

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure

Here is my code that has a function spilling out simple sytle sheets:

```
(defroutes app-routes (GET "/style.css" [] (my-css-function)))
(defn my-css-function [] "(css strings...)")
```

And when I enter "/style.css" in my browser, it spills out plain text strings that can not be used by html file, while being sytanxically correct. I guess compojure is messing with the context type so that the browser is interpreting my string as something strange rather than being a normal css file?

Comment: What do you see in your browser when you "view source?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `my-css-function` returns a string, which **compojure** returns as the content for the response, if no content-type is explicitly specified then my guess is that either `text/plain` or `text/html` are used.

If you want to specify the `text/css` content type for the response, you could do it in the following way:

```
(defn my-css-function [] 
  {:headers {"Content-Type" "text/css"}
   :body "body { background-color: #CCC; }"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code to include the following:

```
  (route/resources "/") ; special route for serving static files like css
                        ; default root directory is resources/public/
```

You may check [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21734158/4058484) for more detail.