# troubleshooting clojure web-app: connecting html and css for heroku deployment

Tags: html, css, web-applications, heroku, clojure

I have two files, one html and one css. I have tried to turn them into a heroku app and even used the lein command to create a heroku friendly skeleton and plug these two files in, but cannot get it to work for the life of me. There is something very basic that I don't yet understand about how to coordinate a view with the back-end control. And the hello world tutorials aren't helping me because they do not show me how to do different things or explain what needs to change in my defroutes function, for example, for that to be accomplished. In short, my question is this:  How can I coordinate these two files into a Clojure project to make the html render as the front page of a webapp and then deploy it on heroku?

html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="sun" src="http://goo.gl/dEEssP">
        <div id='earth-orbit'>
            <img id="earth" src="http://goo.gl/o3YWu9">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.clj file in "lein new heroku ..." project:

```
(ns solar_system.web
  (:require [compojure.core :refer [defroutes GET PUT POST DELETE ANY]]
            [compojure.handler :refer [site]]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [ring.middleware.stacktrace :as trace]
            [ring.middleware.session :as session]
            [ring.middleware.session.cookie :as cookie]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            [ring.middleware.basic-authentication :as basic]
            [cemerick.drawbridge :as drawbridge]
            [environ.core :refer [env]]))

(defn- authenticated? [user pass]
  ;; TODO: heroku config:add REPL_USER=[...] REPL_PASSWORD=[...]
  (= [user pass] [(env :repl-user false) (env :repl-password false)]))

(def ^:private drawbridge
  (-> (drawbridge/ring-handler)
      (session/wrap-session)
      (basic/wrap-basic-authentication authenticated?)))

(defroutes app
  (ANY "/repl" {:as req}
       (drawbridge req))
  (GET "/" []
       {:status 200
        :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
        :body (pr-str ["Hello" :from 'Heroku])})  ; <= Should I change this part here?
  (ANY "*" []
       (route/not-found (slurp (io/resource "404.html")))))

(defn wrap-error-page [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (try (handler req)
         (catch Exception e
           {:status 500
            :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
            :body (slurp (io/resource "500.html"))}))))

(defn -main [& [port]]
  (let [port (Integer. (or port (env :port) 5000))
        ;; TODO: heroku config:add SESSION_SECRET=$RANDOM_16_CHARS
        store (cookie/cookie-store {:key (env :session-secret)})]
    (jetty/run-jetty (-> #'app
                         ((if (env :production)
                            wrap-error-page
                            trace/wrap-stacktrace))
                         (site {:session {:store store}}))
                     {:port port :join? false})))

;; For interactive development:
;; (.stop server)
;; (def server (-main))
```

project.clj file

```
(defproject solar_system "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://solar_system.herokuapp.com"
  :license {:name "FIXME: choose"
            :url "http://example.com/FIXME"}            
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [compojure "1.1.1"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.1.0"]
                 [ring/ring-devel "1.1.0"]
                 [ring-basic-authentication "1.0.1"]
                 [environ "0.2.1"]
                 [com.cemerick/drawbridge "0.0.6"]]
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :plugins [[environ/environ.lein "0.2.1"]]
  :hooks [environ.leiningen.hooks]
  :profiles {:production {:env {:production true}}})
```

example of typical handler code that renders text:

```
(ns hello-world.core
(:use ring.adapter.jetty))

(defn app [req]
    {:status 200
    :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
    :body "Hello, world"}) ; <= Could I just change this part to slurp in
                           ;    the html file and stick it in a file in my 
                           ;    root directory to get a successful 'git push heroku master'?
```

Comment: You might want to include details like what stack you're using and what you've tried.

Comment: I'm a beginner so even the exact meaning of the word "stack" is unclear to me. Is this different from framework or set of libraries I'm using in my project.clj file? I tried to use the tutorial here <https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-clojure> and the "lein new heroku app-name" command from the terminal. I wanna know how the plumbing works, if that makes any sense. If you still don't understand what stack I'm using, could you recommend a good one for me?

Comment: It's your technology stack, like a stack of paper. In this case you are using the `ring` library to define your routes. There are many, many, many ways to serve an index page and it helps significantly to know the specifics of how you want to do it (though `ring` is pretty much the standard way). If you want to be more vague in your questions and want pointers on where to get started on doing something, you may want to consider joining #clojure on freenode irc.

Comment: Whoops, `ring` is for http, I was confusing it with `compojure`. You might want to check out `compojure` to define routes.

Comment: Re-reading the above it looks like you are already using `defroutes`, that's sort of important, and you might, kind of want to post the related code?

Comment: okay, how about this: I am asking for the best way to deploy to heroku using the lein new heroku command, which uses ring and compojure. I understand what a ring handler is and how compojure uses the defroutes macro as a wrapper over that. What I don't understand is exactly how to implement the ring/compojure functions to render my html/css when someone navigates to the URI. Then I want to know how to successfully deploy it to heroku, so that I can easily share the link. I chose this project because it seemed like the simplest type of app I could think of that wasn't just "hello world".

Comment: I'll add some more code in an edit to the main question!

Comment: Cut down your code to bare minimum next time. We don't need to look at your CSS code kthx.

Comment: You're asking two questions: how to render HTML using compojure routes, and how to deploy a ring application on heroku. Keep it to one question per question and be specific.

Comment: got it. I'm new here, so still trying to figure out the balance.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your code:

```
(defroutes app
  (ANY "/repl" {:as req}
       (drawbridge req))
  (GET "/" []
       {:status 200
        :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"} ; change content type
        :body (slurp "resources/public/my-file.html")}) ; wherever your file is
  (ANY "*" []
       (route/not-found (slurp (io/resource "404.html")))))
```

How I'd write it:

```
(defroutes app
  (ANY "/repl" {:as req} (drawbridge req))
  (GET "/" [] (slurp "resources/public/my-file.html")) ; wherever your file is
  (route/resources "/") ; special route for serving static files like css
                        ; default root directory is resources/public/
  (route/not-found (slurp (io/resource "404.html")))) ; IDK what io/resource does
                                                      ; you might not need it
```

Comment: I have used your suggestions and managed to get this to run on the localhost:


        `(defroutes...
        :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
        :body (slurp (io/resource "index.html"))})`


I have a whole new problem now though with the CSS not modifying the html, but I am going to post that in a new question. And I am sure after that I will be posting another one about why it won't deploy on heroku.

Comment: The `(route/resources "/")` solved my case on serving static files. Thanks.